# Get connected Wi-Fi network signal strength with nmcli

Tags: linux, nmcli

I'm able to get the signal strength of all Wi-Fi networks with the following command:

```
$ nmcli -t -f SIGNAL device wifi list
$ 77
  67
  60
  59
  55
  45
  44
  39
  39
  37
```

I would like to reduce this list only to the current Wi-Fi on which I'm connected. I've been through the man page but can't find the necessary flag.

One solution would be to use `sed` or `awk`, but I would like to avoid piping.

Should I use `nmcli device wifi` instead of parsing directly for the SIGNAL column?

Comment: Use `iwconfig` instead.

Comment: Or use the newer `iw scan` etc. instead of the older `iwconfig`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
nmcli --version
nmcli tool, version 1.6.2
```

To get the SIGNAL of the AP on which you are connected, use:

```
nmcli dev wifi list | awk '/\*/{if (NR!=1) {print $7}}'
```

The second `*` mark in `nmcli dev wifi list` is set to identify the SSID on which your are connected.

```
nmcli --version
nmcli tool, version 1.22.10
```

use:

```
nmcli dev wifi list | awk '/\*/{if (NR!=1) {print $6}}'
```

Comment: It works for me if I use `print $6` instead of `print $7`.

Comment: @GrégoireBorel Great! it depend on `nmcli` version.

Comment: Debugging failing scripts if it depends on the nmcli version will be fun...

Comment: This will fail if you connect to SSIDs with varying numbers of spaces in them

Answer (score 6):

The trick here is to use the `-f` parameter of `nmcli` to specify what fields you want in your script.  If you care about the SSID, use the `SSID` field; if you care about which one you're connected to, use the `IN-USE` field:

```
$ nmcli -f IN-USE,SIGNAL device wifi
*  SIGNAL 
   90
*  73     
   40
$ nmcli -f IN-USE,SIGNAL,SSID device wifi
*  SIGNAL  SSID               
   90      wifiWithoutSpaces
*  73      Some Wifi With Spaces
   40      Wifi With a * in its SSID
```

The advantage of ordering the fields in this way is that selecting the signal is a fixed number of column-delimiting characters from the start of the row; we can now use GAD3R's answer without running into column count or nmcli versioning issues:

```
$ nmcli -f IN-USE,SIGNAL,SSID device wifi | awk '/^\*/{if (NR!=1) {print $2}}'
73
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know the name of the network you're connected to, you could modify your approach like this: (for nmcli 1.14.6, other versions may vary)

```
nmcli -t -f SSID,SIGNAL dev wifi list | grep "^<network name>:" | cut -d : -f 2
```

Comment: @telecoM Your command does not work, can you please fix it ?

Comment: @SebMa I think it used to work that way with Debian 9 in late 2018, but now it's different in Debian 10. Edited. Remember to replace `<network name>` with the name of the network.

Comment: @telecoM Now it works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to see the router in use:

```
nmcli -f IN-USE,SIGNAL device wifi | grep '*'
```